# Using fseek to start reading a CSV after a certain number of lines

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I am using the current code to read a csv file and add it to an array:

```
    echo "starting CSV import<br>";
    $current_row = 1; 
    $handle = fopen($csv, "r"); 
    while ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",") ) !== FALSE ) 
    { 
        $number_of_fields = count($data); 
        if ($current_row == 1) { 
        //Header line 
            for ($c=0; $c < $number_of_fields; $c++) 
            { 
                $header_array[$c] = $data[$c]; 
            } 
        } else { 
        //Data line 
            for ($c=0; $c < $number_of_fields; $c++) 
            { 
                $data_array[$header_array[$c]] = $data[$c]; 
            } 

            array_push($products, $data_array);

        } 
        $current_row++; 
    } 
    fclose($handle); 
    echo "finished CSV import <br>";
```

However when using a very large CSV this times out on the server, or has a memory limit error.

I'd like a way to do it in stages, so after the first say 100 lines it will refresh the page, starting at line 101.

I will probably be doing this with a meta refresh and a URL parameter.

I just need to know how to adapt that code above to start at the line I tell it to.

I have looked into fseek() but I'm not sure how to implement this here.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timout can be circumvented using

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

When experiencing problems with the memory limit, it may be wise to take a step back and look at what you're actually doing with the data you're processing. Are you pushing the data into a database? calculate something off the data but don't need to store the actual data, …

Do you really need to push (`array_push($products, $data_array);`) the rows into an array (for later processing)? can you instead write to the database directly? or calculate directly? or build an html `<table>` directly? or whatever the hell you're doing right then an there, within the `while()` loop, without pushing everything into an array first?

If you're able to chunk the processing, I guess you don't need that array at all. Otherwise you'd have to restore the array for every chunk - not solving the memory issue one bit.

If you can manage to change your processing algorithm to waste less memory / time, you should seriously consider that over any chunked processing requiring a round-trip to the browser (for so many performance and security reasons…).

Anyways, you can, at any time, identify the current stream offset with [ftell()](http://php.net/ftell) and re-set to that position using [fseek()](http://php.net/fseek). You'd only need to pass that integer to your next iteration.

---

Also there is no need for your inner `for()` loops. This should produce the same results:

```
<?php

$products = array();
$cols = null;
$first = true; 

$handle = fopen($csv, "r"); 
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== false)  { 
    if ($first) { 
        $cols = $data;
        $first = false;
    } else { 
        $products[] = array_combine($cols, $data);
    }
}

fclose($handle); 
echo "finished CSV import <br>";
```